# Why does this add an extra timestamp when printing?

Tags: python

I use below code add timestamp into print. but it is strange why it add two timestamp around message.

```
old_f = sys.stdout

class CFout:
    def write(self, x):
        old_f.write("%s %s " % (datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f"), x))

sys.stdout = CFout()
```

When I `print True`. it output as below.

```
15/05/2015 05:42:02:121945 True 15/05/2015 05:42:02:121977
```

Before and after `True`, there are two timestamp.
why is this? I only want to add timestamp before `True`.

Comment: You you should use ``logging``for this task: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Answer (score 3):

It's due to the fact that the `print` statement or function performs *two* calls to `write`, one to print the message (`'True'`) and one for the ending newline or space.

You can see this using a script like the following:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

args = []

class CFout:
    def write(self, x):
        args.append(x)
        sys.__stdout__.write("%s %s " % (datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f"), x))


sys.stdout = CFout()

print True
print False
print 1, 2, 3

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print 'arguments were'
print args
```

Called results in:

```
$python2 prnt.py 
15/05/2015 08:07:03:171182 True 15/05/2015 08:07:03:171392 
 15/05/2015 08:07:03:171452 False 15/05/2015 08:07:03:171477 
 15/05/2015 08:07:03:171517 1 15/05/2015 08:07:03:171540   15/05/2015 08:07:03:171561 2 15/05/2015 08:07:03:171581   15/05/2015 08:07:03:171601 3 15/05/2015 08:07:03:171621 
 arguments were
['True', '\n', 'False', '\n', '1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', '\n']
```

Note:

- `'True'` and `'\n'` are the arguments for the two calls performed when doing `print True`.
- `'False'` and `'\n'` are the arguments for the two calls performed when doing `print False`
- `'1'`, `' '`, `'2'`, `' '`, `'3'` and `'\n'` are the arguments performed when doing `print 1,2,3`.

An other way of seeing this is by using exceptions:

```
>>> print 1, 1/0, 2
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Note: the `1` was still printed even though the `1/0` raised an exception. What python is doing is taking each single portion of the stuff to print, evaluating it and then calling `write`. Afterwards it calls `write(' ')` to print the space due to the comma and finally evaluates `1/0` which results in an exception.

In the same way `print True` first evaluates `True`, then calls `write(str(True))` and finally calls `write('\n')` to add the final newline.

If you want to propoerly attach a timestamp to messages you should use the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module instead.

Answer (score 0):

Base on @Bakuriu answer, I am using below code to achieve my object as I am confident that I will not use "\n" in print message. :). I post here if others are also interesting.

```
old_f = sys.stdout
class CFout:
    def write(self, x):
        if x.find("\n") == -1:
            old_f.write("%s %s " % (datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f"), x))
        else:
            old_f.write(x)
sys.stdout = CFout()
```